# Where have my favourite tags gone?

Tags: bug, tag-watching

To navigate the questions on stackoverflow, I have created a list of favourite tags that I frequently visit.

At the time of this writing, no favourite tags are displayed. The sidebar of the questions tab consists of (from top to bottom) Question count, Community ad, Related tags, Hot Network Questions. No favourite tags anywhere.

EDIT: Screen shot showing top of page as displayed by Firefox on Ubuntu Linux.

[image: Top part of the questions page]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot, please?

Comment: Don't you have to be signed in to see favorite tags?

Comment: @muddymess yes, yes you do :)

Comment: @muddymess Thanks alot, that's the cause! I was auto-logged-in to several other stackexchange sites, but stackoverflow behaves differently in this respect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to see favorite tags you need to be signed in to an account on that specific SE site.